# MinMaxScaler only Generating Positive Values

Tags: python, normalization, minmax

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
```

I have a data which contain positive and negative values as given below :

(Here is the csv file of the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Kc3vGDazAPQ_4I7wVvG6VI9Bd9b4uCW/view?usp=sharing)

ext is:
| Index | Values |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1    | -5.473753            |
| 2   | 54.730399            |
| 3   | 0.389353            |
| 4   | -4.156109            |
| 5   | 65.108997            |
| ...   | .........            |
| 733   | 14.082214            |
| 734   | 107.248120            |
| 735   | 54.730399            |

I am trying to use MinMaxScaler as given below:

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
test_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(ext)
predictions_rescaled=min_max_scaler.inverse_transform(test_scaled)
```

predictions_rescaled should be same as ext, because i am scaling it and then rescaling it, but surprisingly both are different. Can anyone guide me where i am making mistake in scaling-rescaling process.

Comment: Could you specify in you post framework used, I mean add required imports. Your goal is to provide a [mcve]. You are close to it.

Comment: provide the ext dataframe also

Comment: @jlandercy i have added the import statement.

Comment: Is there only values column?

Comment: @PrakashDahal i have added ext data .

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, as I have used your data and could reverse it. See my code below.

Comment: I have updated my answer with suggestions to debug the issue.

Comment: For negative value - you probably to keep it negative. So split the scalare for negative values (max is zero) and positive values (min is zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MinMaxScaler** scales the values in range 0 to 1 by default. If you want negative numbers after scaling, you can use **StandardScaler**.

Also there is no wrong in your code. Inverse_transform() is returning the old dataframe.

```py
s_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
test_scaled = s_scaler.fit_transform(ext)
print(test_scaled)
predictions_rescaled=s_scaler.inverse_transform(test_scaled)
print()
predictions_rescaled = pd.DataFrame(predictions_rescaled)
predictions_rescaled
```

Comment: I dont want negative numbers on scaling, but after rescaling i must get original numbers (which do have some negative values as well)

Comment: No I am not getting original values back. Plz check.

Comment: Your current code is for standard scaler and not for MinMaxScaler.

Comment: I have updated it for MinMaxScaler. Is it fine now?

Answer (score 1):

Check which scikit-version you are using and whether there exists a bug in MinMaxScaler. If that is not the problem, check the way you pass in data to MinMaxScaler.

From scikit-learn documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), it should behaviour as expected.

I *cannot reproduce* your problem. It works fine. I get originally back:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pd.read_csv('ext.csv', index_col=0)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df['minmax'] = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df['inv'] = scaler.inverse_transform(df[['minmax']])
```

[image]

Comment: On scaling i am ok with positive numbers (in between 0 to 1), but when i rescaled these numbers i should be getting my original ext data (which contain positive and negative numbers), but this is not happening with the my current code.

Comment: I get the value back with sckit-learn v 0.23